# Fonts in Adobe Reader

Tags: fonts, adobe-acrobat

When I convert a particular document from `.doc` format to a `.pdf` file, the **Shebrew** font turns into small boxes in `Adobe Acrobat`.

When I try to print the document, it prints small boxes rather than the actual font.

I looked at the properties of the document in `Adobe Acrobat` and it says that the document is using the **Shebrew** font.  I sent the document in both `.doc` and `.pdf` format to two other computers and they both had the same problem.

I have the latest edition of Adobe Acrobat. What can I do ?

Comment: Use a different Hebrew font, or test the PDF in Chrome or another PDF reader. Please also include which version of Word you are using (.doc is an old version)

Comment: It didn't work in either Chrome or another PDF reader.

Comment: Are you converting or printing to PDF?

Comment: converting by using the "save as" tab in Word.

Comment: I downloaded cutepdf which is a program which prints to pdf.  Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of PDF settings that might affect this. It's hard to describe exactly because you haven't mentioned exactly how you've created the PDF and with which software).  But ...

If you haven't got the PDF-maker set to embed the font in question OR if the font isn't embeddable (not all of them are), the PDF would generally look ok on your own PC where the font is presumably installed, but not on other PCs where it wouldn't normally be present.

BUT

There's a setting in Acrobat and Reader that says basically "Ignore any fonts installed on my PC.  Use only the fonts embedded in the PDFs I open."  It's a useful setting, because it helps ensure that what you see on your own PC matches what other people see, at least where fonts are concerned.

IF you have that setting enabled and you don't have the problem font embedded in the PDF, that'd explain the problem, I think.

The option is under Edit | Preferences | Page Display.  See if there's a check next to "Use local fonts"

Comment: "Use local fonts" is checked.

Comment: As some of the others have suggested, there may be a problem with the font.  Have you tried a different Hebrew font?